# How to invert and multiply matrices in Android?

Tags: java, android, matrix

Given 2 matrices:

```
public float[] mRi = new float[16];  
public float[] mR = new float[16];
```

These will be the outputs of two readings from

- `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mR, x, y, z)` and
- `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRi, x, y, z)`

So there will be two 4x4 matrices which,

I want to get the result of the following equation:

- `ResultMtrix=inverse(mRi)*mR`

In fact I have the idea whether it works with `invertM()` and `multiplyMM()` but I don't have a clue on how to do it with the matrices.

Can you help?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to set up the matrices in ES format?

Comment: What library are you using?  How are you expecting to get the inverse of a 1x16 (nonsquare) matrix?

Comment: I didn't explained to well what I wanted, actualy this are the outputs of the getRotationMatrix(mR, float[] z,float[] mGdata, float[] mMData)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guy, I assume they are 4x4 matrix (16 elements)... You can use Gauss-Jordan elimination http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination for inversion. Matrix multiplication is described about *everywhere*, even more than matrix inversion.

Answer (score 0):

The *matrices* you are describing are actually **uni-dimensional vectors**, so I am assuming that what you call *inverse* is actually **transpose**. The calculation in that case is quite simple:

## Methods

```
// 1 row * 1 column
public static float scalarMultiplication (float[] m1, float[] m2) {
    if (m1.length != m2.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vectors need to have the same length");
    float m = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<m1.length; i++)
        m += (m1[i]*m2[i]);
    return m;
}

// N rows * N columns
public static float[][] vectorMultiplication (float[] m1, float[] m2) {
    if (m1.length != m2.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vectors need to have the same length");
    float[][] m = new float[m1.length][m1.length];
    for (int i=0; i<m1.length; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<m1.length; j++)
            m[i][j] = (m1[i]*m2[j]);
    return m;
}
```

## Test

```
            float[] m1 = new float[16];
            float[] m2 = new float[16];

            for (int i=0; i<m1.length; i++) {
                m1[i]=i;
                m2[i]=i*i;
            }

            System.out.println ("Multiple is " + scalarMultiplication(m1, m2));
            float[][] m = vectorMultiplication(m1, m2);
            for (int i=0; i<m[0].length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<m[0].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print (m[i][j] +" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

## Output

```
Multiple is 14400.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 4.0 9.0 16.0 25.0 36.0 49.0 64.0 81.0 100.0 121.0 144.0 169.0 196.0 225.0 
0.0 2.0 8.0 18.0 32.0 50.0 72.0 98.0 128.0 162.0 200.0 242.0 288.0 338.0 392.0 450.0 
0.0 3.0 12.0 27.0 48.0 75.0 108.0 147.0 192.0 243.0 300.0 363.0 432.0 507.0 588.0 675.0 
0.0 4.0 16.0 36.0 64.0 100.0 144.0 196.0 256.0 324.0 400.0 484.0 576.0 676.0 784.0 900.0 
0.0 5.0 20.0 45.0 80.0 125.0 180.0 245.0 320.0 405.0 500.0 605.0 720.0 845.0 980.0 1125.0 
0.0 6.0 24.0 54.0 96.0 150.0 216.0 294.0 384.0 486.0 600.0 726.0 864.0 1014.0 1176.0 1350.0 
0.0 7.0 28.0 63.0 112.0 175.0 252.0 343.0 448.0 567.0 700.0 847.0 1008.0 1183.0 1372.0 1575.0 
0.0 8.0 32.0 72.0 128.0 200.0 288.0 392.0 512.0 648.0 800.0 968.0 1152.0 1352.0 1568.0 1800.0 
0.0 9.0 36.0 81.0 144.0 225.0 324.0 441.0 576.0 729.0 900.0 1089.0 1296.0 1521.0 1764.0 2025.0 
0.0 10.0 40.0 90.0 160.0 250.0 360.0 490.0 640.0 810.0 1000.0 1210.0 1440.0 1690.0 1960.0 2250.0 
0.0 11.0 44.0 99.0 176.0 275.0 396.0 539.0 704.0 891.0 1100.0 1331.0 1584.0 1859.0 2156.0 2475.0 
0.0 12.0 48.0 108.0 192.0 300.0 432.0 588.0 768.0 972.0 1200.0 1452.0 1728.0 2028.0 2352.0 2700.0 
0.0 13.0 52.0 117.0 208.0 325.0 468.0 637.0 832.0 1053.0 1300.0 1573.0 1872.0 2197.0 2548.0 2925.0 
0.0 14.0 56.0 126.0 224.0 350.0 504.0 686.0 896.0 1134.0 1400.0 1694.0 2016.0 2366.0 2744.0 3150.0 
0.0 15.0 60.0 135.0 240.0 375.0 540.0 735.0 960.0 1215.0 1500.0 1815.0 2160.0 2535.0 2940.0 3375.0
```